# Angular - Hammerjs - Load html content in swipe action

Tags: javascript, angular, hammer.js

The following swipe action loads three images in the template. They currently work fine but I would like to change two of the images with a functional Google Maps iframe and a loop of checkboxes and names.

I tried replacing the image links with html and changed the `<img [src]="avatar.content" [alt]="">` to `{{avatar.content}}` but the template treated the html as plain text.

What's my best option to get this done?

component.ts

```
SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };

  avatars = [
    {
      content: 'https://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/large/kristy.png',
      visible: true
    },
    {
      content: 'https://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/large/matthew.png',
      visible: false
    },
    {
      content: 'http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/jenny.jpg',
      visible: false
    }
  ];

  // action triggered when user swipes
  swipe(currentIndex: number, action = this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
    // out of range
    if (currentIndex > this.avatars.length || currentIndex < 0) { return };

    let nextIndex = 0;

    // swipe right, next avatar
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
      const isLast = currentIndex === this.avatars.length - 1;
      nextIndex = isLast ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
    }

    // swipe left, previous avatar
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.LEFT) {
      const isFirst = currentIndex === 0;
      nextIndex = isFirst ? this.avatars.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
    }

    // toggle avatar visibility
    this.avatars.forEach((x, i) => x.visible = (i === nextIndex));
  }
```

component.html

```
<div class="swipe-box" *ngFor="let avatar of avatars; let idx=index" (swipeleft)="swipe(idx, $event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe(idx, $event.type)"
    [class.visible]="avatar.visible" [class.hidden]="!avatar.visible">
    <div class="swipe-content">
        <img [src]="avatar.content" [alt]="">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the checkbox loop:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let guest of event['guests'] | keys">
        <md-icon md-list-icon><img class="event-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/70/70" /></md-icon>
        <h3 md-line> {{ guest.value.first_name }} {{guest.value.last_name}} </h3>
        <p md-line>
        </p>
        <span flex>
            <md-checkbox *ngIf="checkGuest(guest.key) === false" (change)="checkIn(guest.key)"></md-checkbox>
            <md-checkbox *ngIf="checkGuest(guest.key) === true" (change)="checkOut(guest.key)" [checked]="true === true"></md-checkbox>
        </span>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: where is checkIn, checkout function

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the difficulty is here.  You've got an index that tracks where you are and several things you want to show.  Just use some conditionals tracking that index and show different templates/html chunks/directives based off that index.

```
<div *ngIf='currentIndex == 1'><img></div>
<div *ngIf='currentIndex == 2'><iframe></div>
```

That template logic would live under '.swipe-content' div in your example.  You probably need to modify your typescript code a little bit so currentIndex is defined/tracked as a variable available to your component's template if it isn't (looks like it just gets passed into a function here).

Answer (score 0):

Try this library   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-carousel. It have all the functionality you need and it is easy to use